# Sharepoint login via apppool user in .Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, iis-7

I am using .net for my web application, and by hardcode username password. Sharepoint site is easily accessible.

But now i want to make some changes in application so need to login into sharepoint without passing hardcoded username and password.

Is it possible to comnect sharepoint and fetch file details by web application without passing hardcoded credentials.

** Basically my apppool user is having  access for sharepoint path that i want to read file.andi want to login into sharepoint via appool user, without passing hardcoded credentials. **

Code snippet i tried but did not work :

```
                using (var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = (CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials) as SharePointOnlineCredentials;
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web web = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            }
```

Code snippet i tried but did not work

```
                using (var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                CredentialCache credCache = new CredentialCache();
                credCache.Add(new Uri(siteUrl), "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials);
                ctx.Credentials = credCache;
                ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web web = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            }
```

Code snippet i tried but did not work

```
                using (var ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                ctx.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web web = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

Please help

Comment: I read multiple articles, but after implementing suggestions it shows 403 error. Currently sharepoint v13 dll are in use

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules FRT might tell you more about that 403. Your next move really depends on what it tells.

Comment: 403 indicates a permission problem. What methods have you tried? Are there any more error messages?

Comment: @samwu just updated the question with with code also.

Comment: Then you can try to use failed request tracking.